# Raspberry PI Laptop Ethernet Connectivity Issue

Tags: pi-3, networking, ethernet, connection

I setup my headless Raspberry PI and called it Optimus. I connect my Windows 10 desktop machine to the Raspberry PI via an ethernet cable. If I ping optimus.local I get a response and can SSH into it - no issues.

**Based on the above I am sure my Raspberry PI is configured correctly.**

However, from my Windows 10 laptop following the same process as above, does not work (**can't ping optimus.local and therefore can't SSH**). So clearly, there must be a configuration element of sorts on my laptop that needs to be checked / changed in order for this to work as it does on my desktop machine.

Any ideas what I need to look out for on my laptop? Please advise.

Comment: what operating systems are running on the non pi's

Comment: Both are Windows 10 OS that SSH into the PI. Edited my question include Windows 10 description.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a question belonging to Raspberry Pi. It is a problem with MS Windows. But because it is an often seen problem together with Raspberry Pi I will give a hint.

Raspbian uses a [Link-local address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address) if there is no DHCP server present. For these addresses there is a top level DNS domain `.local` reserved so you can address link-local addresses with this domain, e.g. **raspberrypi.local**. To manage this there is a service needed, called `mDNS` (multicast Domain Name Service). Microsoft ignores this specification for a long time and used DNS domain `.local` for its own interests (for private home networks, e.g. **raspberrypi.mshome.com**). So it was not possible to address **raspberrypi.local** with MS Windows.

Only since MS Windows 10 Microsoft has implemented **mDNS** as you can see with your Desktop PC. If it doesn't run on your Laptop then you should look for the service managing **mDNS** and link-local addresses. Compare it with your Desktop PC.

Comment: Thanks for the HINT! I did have Bonjour installed - but it seems that the version I had did not install Bonjour Service. I updated it to version 3, Bonjour Service running and can ping and SSH.