# How to Connect Raspberry Pi 3 to Laptop via Ethernet Cable

Tags: hdmi, ethernet-port, laptop

How do I display Raspberry Pi 3 screen onto laptop?

I followed instructions to set up Raspberry Pi here, https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/raspberry-pi-setting-up

I got up to here, https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/raspberry-pi-setting-up/5. When I plugged in power, I did not see three raspberries on screen.

Here is what I did so far:

1. Formatted SD card and copied extracted NOOB files to SD card
2. Plugged in power cord to Raspberry Pi 3 (red light is on)
3. Connected HDMI cable from Raspberry Pi to Windows 10 Laptop
4. Connected Ethernet cable from Raspberry Pi to Windows 10 Laptop (green light is on)

Now, I am following instructions here, https://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-connect-raspberry-pi-to-laptop-display/

I got up to the part,

`For sharing internet to multiple users over Ethernet, go to Network and Sharing Center. Then click on the WiFi network:
Click on Properties (shown below), then go to Sharing and click on “Allow other network users to connect”.`

How do I change Network Connection to Local Area Network? Is this even required in my case? This is where the confusion starts.

Then I proceed to find IP address by going to command prompt on Laptop.

Ethernet IP is 192.168.137.1. I can ping it, but when I type `arp -a` I get `No ARP Entries Found.`

Here is how my network looks

[image]

Can you guide in troubleshooting? Are there an easier set of instructions to follow? Please help!!!!!

#### Tried following, still no luck

Downloaded iTunes. Unzipped with 7Zip. Installed Bonjour 3

[image]

When I scan for IPs, I get this -  I cannot ping any of these IP addresses

[image]

However when I ping `raspberrypi.local`, I get the following:

```
Pinging raspberrypi.local [fe80::fe78:f803:2dcb:3a78%17] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from fe80::fe78:f803:2dcb:3a78%17: time<1ms
Reply from fe80::fe78:f803:2dcb:3a78%17: time<1ms
Reply from fe80::fe78:f803:2dcb:3a78%17: time<1ms
Reply from fe80::fe78:f803:2dcb:3a78%17: time<1ms

Ping statistics for fe80::fe78:f803:2dcb:3a78%17:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

When I SSH (via Putty) to `raspberrypi.local` I get following error

[image]

Comment: If you're using noobs you'll need to set it up with an actual monitor to install an OS. To view the display on your laptop you'll need to setup a VNC server once you've installed raspian. The easiest way might be to flash raspian to the sd card and then you should be able to plug the ethernet cable in and connect it to your laptop. Plugging a hdmi cable directly from your pi to the laptop won't do anything as I doubt the laptop has a hdmi input only output the same as the pi.

Comment: @rohtua You mean connect Raspberry Pi to Sony Bravia (what we have) via HDMI?

Comment: If Sony Bravia is your TV/physical monitor then yes. Plugging it directly into a laptop hdmi wont do anything as it's not an input just an output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are some problems using NOOBS then I suggest to flash your favorite [Raspbian image](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) direct to the SD Card. Most of us do it because it is less error prone. How to do it look at [Installing operating system images](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/README.md).

You wrote that you connected HDMI cable from Raspberry Pi to Windows 10 Laptop. This is not possible. Both HDMI ports are outputs. You have to connect a HDMI output to a HDMI input as you find on most modern monitor. So connect your RasPi to a monitor or a TV with HDMI input.

If you connected the RasPi to the MS Windows 10 laptop by ethernet you should be able to `ping raspberrypi.mshome.com` from the laptop. It's also possible to install **Bonjour for MS Windows** (some infos see also https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/94629/79866). Then you should be able to `ping raspberrypi.local`.

Make sure that **ssh** is enabled on the RasPi. You can do it by putting an empty file named `ssh` into the `/boot` directory with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo touch /boot/ssh
```

Then reboot.

Comment: I flashed the SD disk. Advanced IP Scanner shows `raspberrypi.mshome.com`, which I can ping. Which Bonjour for Windows do I download. I know it's related to networking but https://support.apple.com/downloads/bonjour%2520networking%2520windows does not show Networking

Comment: @Marium Thanks for the info. I have updated the answer in the last paragraph. There you find a link to an accepted answer using Bonjour for Windows. *@c0D3l0g1c* confirmed in his comment, that it's working. If my answer help you a bit, it would be nice if you could accept it with a tick on tick on the left side. This will finish the question and show others that it has a solution.

Comment: Will try this in next few days.Once I'm successful I shall certainly give `tick`

Comment: I updated question ….. tried and still no luck :-(

Comment: @Marium As you wrote you can `ping raspberrypy.local`. So installing Bonjour for Windows is OK and the network is definitely reachable. You are doing something wrong with **putty**. With ssh you would do `ssh pi@raspberrypi.local`. Do you use user **pi** with putty?

Comment: I tried this some more. Turns out in Raspberry Pi 3, ssh is not enabled. I ended up creating blank text file named `ssh` and copied it into the boot drive of Raspberry Pi 3. Now it works. Marking your answer as solution (if possible, please add this troubleshooting step for future users)

Comment: @Marium I have updated the answer with the last paragraph.